# Get complex output type of function that returns record in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to write nice and detailed report on functions in my postgresql database.
I built the following query:

```
SELECT routine_name, data_type, proargnames
FROM   information_schema.routines
join pg_catalog.pg_proc on pg_catalog.pg_proc.proname = information_schema.routines.routine_name
WHERE specific_schema = 'public'
ORDER  BY routine_name;
```

It works as it should (basically returns me what I want it to: function name, output data type and input data type) except one thing:
I have relatively complicated functions and many of them return `record`.
The thing is, `data_type` returns me `record` as well for such functions, while I want detailed list of function output types.
For instance, I have something like this in one of my functions:

```
RETURNS TABLE("Res" integer, "Output" character varying) AS
```

How can I make query above (or, perhaps, a new query, if it will solve the problem) return something like
`integer, character varying` instead of `record` for such functions?
I am using postgresql 9.2
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RECORD` returned value is evaluated at runtime, there is no way that the information can be retrieved this way.

BUT, if `RETURNS TABLE("Res" integer, "Output" character varying) AS` is used, there is a solution.

The test functions I used:

```
-- first function, uses RETURNS TABLE
CREATE FUNCTION test_ret(a TEXT, b TEXT) 
  RETURNS TABLE("Res" integer, "Output" character varying) AS $$
DECLARE                           
  ret RECORD;                                                                                   
BEGIN                           
  -- test
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- second function, test some edge cases
-- same name as above, returns simple integer
CREATE FUNCTION test_ret(a TEXT)
  RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  ret RECORD;
BEGIN
-- test
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How to retrieve this function return datatype is easy as it's stored into `pg_catalog.pg_proc.proallargtypes`, the problem is that this is an array of OID. We must unnest this thing and join it to `pg_catalog.pg_types.oid`.

```
-- edit: add support for function not returning tables, thx Tommaso Di Bucchianico
WITH pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes AS (
   SELECT
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.oid,
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.proname,
      CASE WHEN proallargtypes IS NOT NULL THEN unnest(proallargtypes) ELSE null END AS proallargtype
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
      JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_proc.pronamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
    WHERE pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname = 'public'
),
  pg_proc_with_proallargtypes_names AS (
    SELECT
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.oid,
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.proname,
      array_agg(pg_catalog.pg_type.typname) AS proallargtypes
    FROM pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes
      LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type ON pg_catalog.pg_type.oid = proallargtype
    GROUP BY
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.oid,
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.proname
  )
SELECT
  information_schema.routines.specific_name,
  information_schema.routines.routine_name,
  information_schema.routines.routine_schema,
  information_schema.routines.data_type,
  pg_proc_with_proallargtypes_names.proallargtypes
FROM information_schema.routines
    -- we can declare many function with the same name and schema as long as arg types are different
    -- This is the only right way to join pg_catalog.pg_proc and information_schema.routines, sadly
 JOIN pg_proc_with_proallargtypes_names 
    ON pg_proc_with_proallargtypes_names.proname || '_' ||  pg_proc_with_proallargtypes_names.oid = information_schema.routines.specific_name
;
```

Any refactoring is welcome :)

Here is the result:

```
 specific_name  | routine_name | routine_schema | data_type |      proallargtypes      
----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+--------------------------
 test_ret_16633 | test_ret     | public         | record    | {text,text,int4,varchar}
 test_ret_16635 | test_ret     | public         | integer   | {NULL}
(2 rows)
```

---

**EDIT** 
Identification of input and output arguments is not trivial, here is my solution for pg 9.2

```
-- https://gist.github.com/subssn21/e9e121f6fd5ff50f688d
-- Allow us to use array_remove in pg < 9.3
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_remove(a ANYARRAY, e ANYELEMENT)
  RETURNS ANYARRAY AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN array(SELECT x FROM unnest(a) x WHERE x <> e);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- edit: add support for function not returning tables, thx Tommaso Di Bucchianico
WITH pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes AS (
    SELECT
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.oid,
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.proname,
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.proargmodes,
      CASE WHEN proallargtypes IS NOT NULL THEN unnest(proallargtypes) ELSE null END AS proallargtype
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
      JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_proc.pronamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
    WHERE pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname = 'public'
),
pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode AS (
    SELECT
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.oid,
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.proname,
      pg_catalog.pg_type.typname,
      -- we can't unnest multiple array of same length the way we expect in pg 9.2
      -- just retrieve each mode manually using type row_number
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.proargmodes[row_number() OVER w] AS proargmode
    FROM pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes
      LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type ON pg_catalog.pg_type.oid = proallargtype
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes.proname)
),
pg_proc_with_input_and_output_type_names AS (
    SELECT
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.oid,
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.proname,
      array_agg(pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.typname) AS proallargtypes,
      -- we should use FILTER, but that's not available in pg 9.2 :(
      array_remove(array_agg(
          -- see documentation for proargmodes here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-proc.html
          CASE WHEN pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.proargmode = ANY(ARRAY['i', 'b', 'v'])
          THEN pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.typname 
          ELSE NULL END
      ), NULL) AS proinputargtypes,
      array_remove(array_agg(
         -- see documentation for proargmodes here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-proc.html
         CASE WHEN pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.proargmode = ANY(ARRAY['o', 'b', 't'])
         THEN pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.typname
         ELSE NULL END
      ), NULL) AS prooutputargtypes
    FROM pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode
    GROUP BY
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.oid,
      pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes_names_and_mode.proname
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM pg_proc_with_input_and_output_type_names
;
```

And here is my sample output:

```
  oid  |   proname    |      proallargtypes      | proinputargtypes | prooutputargtypes 
-------+--------------+--------------------------+------------------+-------------------
 16633 | test_ret     | {text,text,int4,varchar} | {text,text}      | {int4,varchar}
 16634 | array_remove | {NULL}                   | {}               | {}
 16635 | test_ret     | {NULL}                   | {}               | {}
(3 rows)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: You need also a CASE statement in the subquery, otherwise the query will ignore the other functions:  `CASE WHEN proallargtypes IS NOT NULL THEN unnest(proallargtypes) ELSE null END AS proallargtype`

Comment: Thx, I fixed both queries to support other functions and functions with same name

Comment: @Clément Prévost Thank you for your help, your answer helped me to understand this problem better and saved a lot of time. However, for some reason, columns `proinputargtypes` and `prooutputargtypes` resulted empty (by 'empty' I mean filled with `{}` only, not `NULL`s) on my machine after I executed your script: I even created separate database with functions you used to test your solution only, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, provided by Clément Prévost, is detailed and educative and therefore I marked it as best, while, however, after I executed suggested script I ended up with empty (filled only by `{}`) `proinputargtypes` and `prooutputargtypes` columnes on my machine. So I conducted a little research on my own, using hints that I learned from the answer above, and wrote following query:

```
WITH pg_proc_with_unhandled_proallargtypes AS (
    SELECT
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.oid,
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.proname,
      pg_catalog.pg_proc.proargmodes,
      CASE WHEN proallargtypes IS NOT NULL THEN cast(proallargtypes AS text) ELSE NULL END AS proallargtype,
      CASE WHEN array_agg(proargtypes) IS NOT NULL THEN  replace(string_agg(proargtypes::text, ','), ' ', ',') ELSE NULL END AS proargtype
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
      JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_proc.pronamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
    WHERE pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname = 'public'
    GROUP BY pg_catalog.pg_proc.oid, pg_catalog.pg_proc.proname, pg_catalog.pg_proc.proargmodes, proallargtype
    ),

pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes AS( 
SELECT proname, CASE WHEN char_length(proargtype) =0 THEN NULL
    ELSE ('{' || proargtype || '}')::oid[] end AS inp,
    CASE WHEN proallargtype is NULL THEN NULL ELSE replace(proallargtype, proargtype || ',', '')::oid[] end AS output
FROM pg_proc_with_unhandled_proallargtypes
),

smth_input AS(
SELECT proname, unnest(inp) AS inp FROM pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes
),

smth_output AS(
SELECT proname, unnest(output) AS output FROM pg_proc_with_unnested_proallargtypes
),

input_unnested AS(
SELECT proname, string_agg(pg_catalog.pg_type.typname::text, ',') AS fin_input FROM smth_input
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type ON pg_catalog.pg_type.oid = inp
GROUP BY proname
),

output_unnested AS (
SELECT proname,  string_agg(pg_catalog.pg_type.typname::text, ',') AS fin_output FROM smth_output
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type ON pg_catalog.pg_type.oid = output
GROUP BY proname
)

SELECT input_unnested.proname, fin_input, CASE WHEN fin_output IS NOT NULl THEN fin_output ELSE information_schema.routines.data_type end AS fin_output
FROM input_unnested
LEFT JOIN output_unnested ON input_unnested.proname = output_unnested.proname
JOIN information_schema.routines ON information_schema.routines.routine_name = input_unnested.proname
```

It might be inefficient a bit and I probably used too much explicict type casting, but it worked.